# C++ встроенный компилятор ассемблера (__asm) выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ассемблер

```
    #include <iostream>

int main()
{
    __asm {
        mov dx, hello;
        mov ah, 9;
        int 21h;
        mov ax, 4C00h;
        int 21h;
        hello db 'Hello, world!$'
    };
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, а вы думаете, что оно в принципе будет работать? Функции DOS в программе Windows?

Comment: языки Fasm и Masm,как я понял,не особо похожи?))))

Comment: Можно как-нибудь писать в языке C++ на Fasm?

Comment: В данном случае я имел в виду, что даже если вы напишете верно, и оно даже скомпилируется - работать это не станет, потому что `int 21h` - это голый 16-битный DOS...

Comment: Тогда не могли бы вы показать,как вывести Hello World на экран?

Comment: Через прерывание DOS? Делать 16-битную программу...

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно просто вывести строку с помощью ассемблерной вставки - ну, вот пример с использование стандартной библиотеки.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char hello[] = "Hello, world\0";
    __asm {
        lea eax, DWORD PTR hello
        push    eax
        call    puts
        add esp, 4
    };
}
```

Только это должно быть 32-битное консольное приложение (64-битные не поддерживают вставки `asm`, по крайней мере в Visual Studio 2017).

Если вам нужны именно функции DOS (`int 21h`) - то нужно искать старенький компилятор, который будет создавать 16-битное приложение...